# Netlogo Sprouting turtles spaced at less than one patch

Tags: netlogo

I want to place turtles on each of the black patches(below Figure) such that there is no gap between turtles at all:

[image]

Code I use right now:

```
ask patches with [pcolor = black][sprout-dead-turtles wall-agents [set color red]]
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

But I want to place turtles in between each of the two patches as well. So that I can cover the showing black part.

Note: Changing the shape of turtles is no use to my purpose though it would cover the black area. My aim to create a replusion force field from these agents and gaps in between are loop holes from where agents may escape.[Somewhat similar to agents bouncing back on a wall].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fun solution:

```
breed [ dead-turtles dead-turtle ]

to setup
  ca  
  ; draw the background:
  ask patches with [ abs pxcor != max-pxcor and abs pycor != max-pycor ] [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pycor = max-pycor and abs pxcor <= 1 ] [ set pcolor white ]
  set-default-shape dead-turtles "circle"

  ; sprout a first set of turtles:
  ask patches with [ pcolor = black ] [
    sprout-dead-turtles 1 [ set color red ]
  ]

  ; create temporary links between these, and use the
  ; links to place a new set of turtles in between:
  ask dead-turtles [
    create-links-with turtles-on neighbors4 
  ]
  ask links [
    let target end2
    ask end1 [
      hatch 1 [
        face target
        fd distance target / 2
      ]
    ]
    die ; remove the link
  ]
end
```

I'm not saying that it is the only possible solution, but it's simple enough, and it works. (World wrapping has to be turned off, though, which I assume is the case.)

Comment: THANKS!!This create turtles at 0.5 distance what if I want to vary the distance for example create turtles at 0.3 distance.

Comment: That's a little different: you'd need to hatch a turtle from _both_ ends of the links and have each one move 0.3 towards the other end.

Comment: I don't quite get to modify the code to accomplish this. Are you saying to add another ask for end2, but where should it face in that case? Can please modify the code to elucidate your modification? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please expound upon your methodology by code. It will help me better in understanding. Do you think there is any other way to this? THANKS!

Comment: When you asked about 0.3, I thought that you now wanted _two_ turtles between each pair of original turtles, each of the new turtles at a specific distance (i.e., 0.3) from one of the old ones. That's why I said you needed to hatch another one from `end2`. But now I'm thinking that maybe you just want `fd 0.3 * distance target` instead of `fd distance target / 2`. If that is not the case, please ask a different question; comments are not the place for this, and I think your original question has already been answered.

Comment: This don't seem to seem to solve the problem. Please check the new question asked as you said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346125/netlogo-sprouting-turtles-at-regular-intervals

Comment: I love this solution because it leads to a shape-agnostic solution where any perimeter of turtles, where each turtle knows or can easily discover its neighbors could be made more (or less) dense.