# Sprouting turtles in between extended issue

Tags: netlogo

This is question is an extension of the previous question.
[Netlogo Sprouting turtles at regular intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346125/netlogo-sprouting-turtles-at-regular-intervals)

On runnning the code and set the turtle size to about 0.4. I face the following issue:(Check figure below)
[image: Simulation run]

[image: Problem issue]

In figure 2, you can notice the black gap where there no turtles. This is undesirable and is what I am intending correct. So in a way the sprout should begin at the edge of patch instead the center.

Thanks.

CODE:(Answer by [Nicolas Payette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487946/nicolas-payette) on [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346125/netlogo-sprouting-turtles-at-regular-intervals))

```
to fill-wall [ d ]
  set d precision d 1 ; make sure d is a multiple of 0.1
  let n precision (d / 0.1) 0 ; interval at which to hatch
  ask one-of possible-next-patches [ 
    sprout 1 [
      hatch 1
      let i 0
      let next-patch my-next-patch
      while [ next-patch != nobody ] [
        face next-patch
        while [ patch-ahead 0.55 != nobody and [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 0.55 = black ] [
          fd 0.1
          setxy precision xcor 1 precision ycor 1 ; avoid floating point imprecisions
          set i i + 1
          if i mod n = 0 [ hatch 1 ]
        ]
        set next-patch my-next-patch
      ]
      die
    ]
  ]  
end

to-report possible-next-patches
  let empty-black-patches patches with [ pcolor = black and not any? turtles-here ]
  report empty-black-patches with [
    count neighbors4 with [ member? self empty-black-patches ] = 1
  ]
end

to-report my-next-patch
  report one-of possible-next-patches with [ member? self [ neighbors4 ] of myself ]
end
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
to setup
  ca  
  ; draw the background:
  ask patches with [ abs pxcor != max-pxcor and abs pycor != max-pycor ] [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pycor = max-pycor and abs pxcor <= 1 ] [ set pcolor white ]
  set-default-shape turtles "circle 2"
  fill-wall 0.3
end
```

Constraints:

- `d` has to be a multiple of 0.1
- world wrapping needs to be turned off

Comment: Impossible to advise you unless you provide code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing @SethTisue. I have code now. Please check.

Comment: Do you understand why the problem happens? Do you have an idea for fixing it yourself? Do you understand Nicolas's code? You need to ask something more specific besides “here is a bunch of code, fix it for me”. Tell us your idea for fixing it, tell us you exactly what you tried, and tell us exactly where you get stuck. *That* is what a question is. Stack Overflow isn't a site where other people write your code for you for free. It's a site where if you do the work to write a good question, someone will answer.