# Wall agents in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to simulate a room with opening door. Instead of using patches I wish to use agents.

The earlier approach I followed was first creating a box with a gap and then distributing agents on it.
But it didn't seem give the results.

([Netlogo Sprouting turtles at regular intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346125/netlogo-sprouting-turtles-at-regular-intervals)

[Netlogo Sprouting turtles spaced at less than one patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221007/netlogo-sprouting-turtles-spaced-at-less-than-one-patch))

Above is roughly sketched diagram.
[image]

Note:
An easier to do it would to sprout turtles at each patch. But I don't require so. Instead I wish to make turtles small and sprout one more than at a patch.
Thanks.

Question: distribute turtles along the sides of a rectangle (with a gap as shown in fig) and distribution can be varied depending upon the desired density of turtles.

Comment: So, what is your question? This seems to end before you get to the part where you actually ask something.

Comment: @SethTisue Please check I have made it more clear.

Comment: The question is now clearer, but you're still the missing the part where you do some of the work yourself, instead of just asking other people to write your code for you. Try to solve it yourself; if you get stuck, post the code you wrote, explain the approach you were trying to take, and explain exactly where you got stuck and why. *That's* what a question is.

Comment: I could solve it see the answer below @SethTisue, though a primitive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does the job in case someone in future faces such a issue:

```
set breadth-patches patches with[(pycor > (-(breadth)) and pycor < breadth and pxcor = lengthrec) or(pycor > (-(breadth)) and pycor < breadth and pxcor = (-(lengthrec))) ]
  set length-patches patches with[(pxcor > (-(lengthrec)) and pxcor < lengthrec and pycor = (-(breadth - 1))) or (pxcor > (-(lengthrec)) and pxcor < lengthrec and pycor = (breadth - 1))]
  set gap-patches patches with [pxcor > (gap * (-1)) and pxcor < gap and pycor =(breadth - 1)]
  set length-patches length-patches with [not member? self gap-patches]



ask breadth-patches[

sprout-walls 1[set color 2
  set size 0.5 set heading 180 fd 0.25
  if-else(pxcor < 0)[set heading 90][set heading 270] fd 0.25]
sprout-walls 1[set color 2
  set size 0.5 set heading 360 fd 0.25
 if-else(pxcor < 0)[set heading 90][set heading 270] fd 0.25]

]
  ask length-patches[

    sprout-walls 1[set color 2
      set size 0.5 set heading 90  fd 0.25
         if-else(pycor < 0)[set heading 180][set heading 0] fd 0.25
      ]
   sprout-walls 1[set color 2
     set size 0.5 set heading 270 fd 0.25
         if-else(pycor < 0)[set heading 180][set heading 0] fd 0.25
     ]
   ]  
end
```